# Redirect output from a multiprocess?

Tags: python, windows, multiprocessing

I am having trouble logging everything that happens in a called multi processed module.

Script: mainScript.py

```
import multiprocessing
python_file = A different python file
def main():
    module = __import__(python_file)
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=getattr(module, 'main'), args=())
    p.start()
    step_timeout = 20
    p.join(step_timeout)
```

Script: A different python file

```
import os
def main():
    print('I am a different python script')
    os.system('dir').read()
    os.system("call C:\\test.bat")
    return
```

I am having trouble logging the output from the batch files that are called as well as the result of `os.system(command).read()`.

I know you can log everything that run through a python script doing something like this...

```
python mainScript.py >> logFile.txt
```

Is it possible I can do something like this with the multiprocessing output?

```
p = multiprocessing.Process(target=getattr(module, 'main'), args=()) >> logFile.txt
```

If so, will it also capture the output of the batch scripts?

Is it possible to redirect everything that is printed in my called process to the main process?

Comment: `os.system()` doesn't return something with a `read()` method — on Windows, the return value is that returned by the system shell after running the command. I suggest you use `subprocess.call()` instead. because you can pass it a `stdout=` keyword argument that you could use to retrieve the output. I also suggest you narrow your question down...a better starting point might be asking about how to capture the output from a Windows batch script.

Comment: multiprocessing doesn't allow using the process startup info to override the standard handles of a child process when it calls `CreateProcess`. Even if we temporarily redirect the standard handles in the parent via `SetStdHandle`, it's of no use if the current process is a GUI app (e.g. pythonw.exe or a similar frozen executable). Windows only duplicates the parent's standard handles to the child if the child is a console application. The reliable solution is to use `subprocess.Popen`, as suggested above.